# what's the best way to program this project?

Tags: flash, timeline

I've used Macromedia Director and Adobe Flash (animate cc now) but I don't want to spend the money on Animate CC.  I'm thinking there's either an open source alternative or free programming language that would suit my needs?

Anyway, the project involves my genealogy research.  I want to create a map of Europe and the U.S. that moves through time (timeline on the bottom with controls) from about 50 a.d. through the present day and reads in information from external .txt files where I put information about the different generations of ancestors I've dug up.

For each person in the file I will include Name: Birth date & Location, any intermediate moves and their dates, and death date and location.  As the years scroll by the program will search for people born in that year, populate the map with male/female icons and names in the correct location, and then remove them when they die.

I'll have 2 external files - 1 will be direct ancestors and 1 will be cousins who are not direct which will will have icons that aren't as bright and bold as the direct ancestors.

I've done basic programming in the past with linear languages, and more extensive projects with timeline based programming like Director/Flash which to me seem well suited to this project.  And, I have to be able to do this on a Mac.  Can anyone give me recommendations and reasonings?  Thanks!

Comment: Adobe provides Flex/AIR SDKs (they are Java-based and thus cross-platform) for free so you can create pure AS3 (means you don't involve FLA sources) projects and build (you can build regular SWFs for browsers) them. That leaves you to pick an AS3-friendly IDE that will still run on Mac. You can try FDT (has a basic free edition) https://fdt.powerflasher.com/buy-download/ or IntelliJ Idea (but for AS3 projects you will still have to buy it, I think). You can browse this thread too: https://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/as3-ide-2018

Comment: I'm also looking at Synfig, which I just discovered.  I like the GUI but I don't know if the scripting is capable of doing what I want.

Comment: Just thinking out loud here but would a combination of a database, php and javascript be easier for this type of project?